# my react-node app is running good but when i import {Provider} from react-redux it give error

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
my package.json includes 
 "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react": "^16.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.1.0",
    "react-html-email": "^3.0.0",
    "react-redux": "^4.4.5",
    "react-route": "^1.0.3",
    "react-router": "^3.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-router-redux": "4.0.4",
    "redux": "3.5.2",
    "redux-thunk": "2.0.1",
```

and the on importing Provider on index.js 
import {Provider} from 'react-redux'
the error pop out

```
storeShape.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'shape' of undefined
    at Object.<anonymous> (storeShape.js:7)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 6f1183e2a6794c3bb2e7:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 6f1183e2a6794c3bb2e7:86)
    at Object.<anonymous> (Provider.js:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (bundle.js:51889)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 6f1183e2a6794c3bb2e7:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 6f1183e2a6794c3bb2e7:86)
    at Object.<anonymous> (index.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap 6f1183e2a6794c3bb2e7:555)
    at fn (bootstrap 6f1183e2a6794c3bb2e7:86)
```

i make just one change and i am new in redux so kindly help

Comment: i have  "prop-types": "^15.6.0", installed

Comment: have you tried a much higher version of `react-redux`? Try install `react-redux` v5.0.6

Comment: waoo updating react-redux work for me. thanku sir

Comment: That's great. I will add this as an answer. Please tick this as an accepted answer so that the next person who runs into the same issue can get the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/822) having a bad `npm` cache or the wrong `react-redux` version causes the error you're having. Therefore, updating the version of your `react-redux` should solve the problem. If not, consider clearing your `npm` cache and try run your app again.